# Is QGIS-OSGeo4W-2.14.2-2-Setup-x86.exe last version for XP 32 bit?

Tags: qgis, installation, windows

I have tried to install QGIS 2.14 LTR, but the application crashes (Error: Qgis-ltr-bin.exe :entry point was not found…. GetLogicalProcessor…. KERNEL32.dll)

QGIS-OSGeo4W-2.14.2-2-Setup-x86.exe and previous releases have about 340 MB, next releases only about 290 MB, QGIS-OSGeo4W-2.14.2-2-Setup-x86.exe is the last version, which I can use. Following versions crash. Is it related to missing files in the install packages?

Windows XP 32 bit

Comment: At a guess: this may have something to do with Windows XP, which is no longer officially supported by Microsoft. You may try getting the latest service pack (3?) if you don't already have it.